# InfoPath 2010: no publish button

Tags: xml, infopath, publishing, infopath2010

I am working on learning how to use InfoPath and I don't know what's going on.

If you, look at the screenshot attached you can see that there isn't a publish button only the 'Save a snapshot' one. Yet everywhere I read there should be a button in the list with the Print, Save & Send, etc yet I don't see one and you can see in the screenshot that it's not there.

Any idea what I'm missing?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you opened the form template in **Infopath Filler**, i.e. in Preview of an XML  data form created on the basis of that XSN form template.

Instead of double-clicking on the file in Windows Explorer, right click it and choose **Design** option (instead of **Open** to open in Infopath Filler) to open it in **Infopath Designer**.

Or open **Infopath Designer** and choose on ribbon **File** > **Open** > ...

Comment: It wouldn't be possible to ever earn any money if everybody always felt smart